# Вывод наибольшего значения

Tags: php, mysql

Делаю скрипт личных сообщений пользователей.
Есть страница, где выводятся все пользователи которые вели диалог со мной, и на этой странице я хочу сделать чтоб выводило последнее сообщение от кождого пользователя. 
Вывод всех сообщений осуществляю запросом:

```
$MailUS=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `mail` WHERE `id_komu` = '$us[users_id]' GROUP BY id_us ORDER BY wread ASC LIMIT $otkuda, $set_coll_page");
while ($MSGuS = mysql_fetch_array($MailUS))
{
My Code
}
```

Пытался изменить запрос на:

```
$MailUS=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `mail` WHERE `id_komu` = '$us[users_id]' GROUP BY id_us ORDER BY wread ASC LIMIT $otkuda, $set_coll_page");
while ($MSGuS = mysql_fetch_array($MailUS))
{
$MMsg=mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT max(id) FROM `mail` WHERE `id` = '$MSGuS[id_us]' LIMIT 1"));
MyCode
echo "$MSGuS[mess]";
}
```

но ничего не выходит.
буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тогда может так:

```
$MailUS=mysql_query("SELECT id_us FROM mail WHERE id_komu='".$us[users_id]."' GROUP BY id_us ORDER BY wread ASC LIMIT $otkuda, $set_coll_page"); // получаем ID пользователей, которые мне писали
while ($MSGuS = mysql_fetch_array($MailUS)){
    $MMsg=mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mail WHERE id_us='".$MSGuS[id_us]."' order by date desc LIMIT 1"));
    echo "$MSGuS[mess]";
}
```

UPDATE:

```
$MMsg=mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mail WHERE id_us='".$MSGuS[id_us]."' or id_komu='".$MSGuS[id_us]."' order by date desc LIMIT 1"));
```

Comment: теперь выводит последнее сообщение пользователя, но если последнее сообщение было от меня, то мое сообщение не выводиться, а выводится последнее сообщение которое было отправлено мне

Answer (score 0):

1. Измените свои запросы таким образом:

   `$sql = "SELECT * FROM mail WHERE id_komu = '".$us[users_id]."' GROUP BY id_us ORDER BY wread ASC LIMIT ".$otkuda.", ".$set_coll_page;`
2. и попробуйте выполнить их в mysql-консоли - что получится?
3. `echo "$$MSGuS[mess]";` - это не опечатка ($$) ?

UPDATE:

`$sql = "select * from mail where id_us=".$sender_user_id." and id_komu=".$my_user_id." and wread=0 order by date desc limit 0,1";` - выведет последнее непрочитанное сообщение от $sender_user_id, отправленное $my_user_id

Comment: ($$)  это опечатка

Comment: @Денис: c этим разобрались. Теперь - что выводят ваши запросы, если их выполнить в mysql-консоли?

Comment: запрос `$MailUS=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `mail` WHERE `id_komu` = '$us[users_id]' GROUP BY id_us ORDER BY wread ASC LIMIT $otkuda, $set_coll_page");` работает правильно, он должен вывести сообщения пользователей - он их выводит. а мне нужно чтобы вывело только последниее сообщения. ну знаете, например как ВКонтакте, если зайти на страницу сообщений, то видишь Имя Фамилию пользователя и последнее сообщение от этого пользователя. вот я хочу так же сделать, вывод данных о пользователе я сделал, а вот вывод именно ПОСЛЕДНЕГО сообщения не могу

Comment: @Денис: покажите структуру таблицы mail

Comment: **id** - AUTO_INCREMENT, **id_us** - id того кто отправил сообщения, **id_komu** - id того кому было отправлено сообщение, **mess** - текст сообщения, **date** - дата отправки, **wread** - (0 не прочитано - 1 прочитано)

Comment: @Денис:  "id_us - id того кто отправил сообщения, id_us " - да ладно?
Наверно все-таки id_us и id_komu ? Ваш способ именовать переменные и поля таблицы ведет к запутыванию. Гораздо разумнее - id_sender, id_recipient.

Comment: я ошибся при написании комментария, вот структура:  
id - AUTO_INCREMENT, id_us - id того кто отправил сообщения, id_komu - id того кому было отправлено сообщение, mess - текст сообщения, date - дата отправки, wread - (0 не прочитано - 1 прочитано)

Comment: ваш ответ не подходит. так как у меня на странице выводятся все пользователи которые писали мне сообщения, если даже некий пользователь написал мне несколько сообщений, он выведется всего 1 раз. И я хочу сделать чтобы выводилось последнее сообщение с пользователями. с помощью того запроса что предоставил я все это реализуется, но выводит первое сообщение которое было с этим пользователям

Answer (score 0):

При такой структуре БД SQL запросом сделать это получится с огромными костылями, которые будут тормозить все что только можно.
Самый лучший вариант будет немного переделать таблицу

Добавить какое нибудь поле типа `dialog`, в котором будет уникальный ИД диалога пользователей, и группировать по нему.
Получится что то вроде

```
SELECT * FROM `mail` WHERE 
`id_komu` = '$us[users_id]' OR `id_us` = '$us[users_id]'
GROUP BY dialog 
ORDER BY date DESC // Сортируем по дате
LIMIT $otkuda, $set_coll_page
```